# objective c http query

Tags: iphone

Hey, Iam new to objective c and really dont know much about it. I have been given a query that is gonna I need to send data in to the server.Query is like this http://abc.com/insertipademail.php?name=name&email=email I need to enter the name and email I have constructed the string But I dont know how to send it to the server. Can someone help me out please. Or point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, take a look a NSString's [stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:) method.  You could do something like:

```
// NSString * myURLString = whatever you do to build the url
NSURL * myURL =  [NSURL URLWithString: myURLString];
NSString * response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL: myURL encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL];
NSLog(@"The response was: %@", response);
```

As written, this will ignore all errors and perform the request synchronously. In a real app, you probably want to handle any error that occur, and perhaps perform the request in the background.  See the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) for further documentation.  You can also try using any of several open source libraries such as those suggested in David M.'s answer.

Comment: You can use NSURLConnection, as well, but in my experience, the HTTP libraries listed mean a lot less work for the same result. Also, it sounds like the questioner wants to POST, so stringWithContentsOfURL won't work.

Comment: His sample url includes a query string, so it looks like a GET to me.  At any rate, given his stated new-to-Objective-C status, I though it would be best to give the simplest possible solution first in just a couple of lines of code, then build complexity on from there.  I didn't want to overwhelm him with learning how to incorporate a 3rd party library into his app before he understands the basics of the SDK and the language.  Walk before you fly...

Comment: The poor soul's script's name begins with "insert", so it probably *should* be a POST, but probably really is a GET. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks Jason, you are right I couldnt understand the complex stuff yet. What you posted worked like a charm. Gonna do more digging on the other libraries now. Thanks for the help guys, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I like the library [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). There is also [HTTPRiot](http://labratrevenge.com/httpriot/).